# PyBluez and Python 3.3 windows 64 bits

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7-x64

I don't install pybluez on Windows 7 64 bit.
In fact, I use pip to try install PyBluez-0.20-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl.
(http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
But I have this message

0.20-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Someone would have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an official repository. Try just installing it using the normal installers on the Python Package Index (PyPI):

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez

Or use pip to try to install it:

```
pip install pybluez
```

This will cause pip to look at PyPI for this package and try to install it from there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing PyBluez-0.22-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl for Python version 2.7 or PyBluez-0.22-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl for 3.4 and PyBluez-0.22-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl for 3.5. You can pip install one of these based on your Python version. The link to download all these can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez). Worked for me. Hope this helps.